# JQuery resizable snap to other resizable objects' borders?

Tags: jquery, resizable

I wonder why they didn't develope JQuery resizable with option to snap the resizing object to others (instead of snapping to grid) like draggable ? Does anyone know such a plugin to achieve this ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Think this should do the trick:

https://github.com/polomoshnov/jQuery-UI-Resizable-Snap-extension

Comment: Oh my, that all what I needed! Thanks!

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the heads up! Updated.

Comment: Does it only snap to other draggable elements?

Comment: Works wondefully!  I'm on jQuery UI 1.11.4, so don't worry about @RolandSoós comment (unless you're <1.8 maybe?).  I had to tweak the code a little to get it to also work when the objects are not in the same parent absolute-positioning parent (which is how $.ui.draggable.snap behaves).  That change is here in case anyone else has a more complex layout they need to do snapping on: https://github.com/polomoshnov/jQuery-UI-Resizable-Snap-extension/pull/9

Answer (score 1):

For me this javascript add-on provided didn't work, maybe because it's some years outdated. Instead I found a simpliest solution that uses only an original attribute from the **JQuery-UI's** library.

On the dialog you want to **snap**, just make something like:

```
$('.your-dialog-filter').dialog().parents('.ui-dialog').draggable('option', 'snap', true);
```

Simple like this.

More info and demo: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to

Comment: Question is about resizable, draggable snap is easy one.